# Програмироать без клваиатуры

Tags: клавиатура

У меня нет клавиутары, а програмировать хочеться. Как такое возможно?

C телефона счас

Comment: А что у вас есть?

Comment: @DiD по всей видимости клавиатура или мышь точно есть

Comment: @DiD устройство позиционирования курсора типа мыш

Comment: используйте такой же способ, как и при написании данного вопроса :D

Comment: Вы же как то написали текущее сообщение, таким образом и пишите код, как по мне вопрос не уместный в рамках форума

Comment: Этот вопрос напомнил мне тех людей, которые как-бы "учатся" на теории, но никогда не пробуют на практике....

Comment: @Roman я с телефона сижу счас

Comment: Ну если руки, ноги есть - это уже хорошо!

Comment: @HTO на телефоне есть наэкранная клавиатура. Программируйте с телефона!

Comment: ну в крайнем случае можно на телефоне писать код, есть для этого инструменты и их много, а вообще купить клавиатуру разве проблема? ну или использовать экранную клавиатуру, правда это не оченеь удобно

Comment: Termux
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.termux&hl=ru&gl=US
HackersKeyboard
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard&hl=ru&gl=US
Программировать можно на компьютере с телефона по SSH, при этом компьютеру не нужны не только клавиатура, но и мышка и монитор

Comment: На андройд есть и IDE вроде https://www.qpython.com/ или https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.foxdebug.acodefree&hl=ru&gl=US

Comment: ssh сила. ну и куча других есть еще возможностей удаленного доступа... плюс что-то можно и на телефоне программировать...я на AIDE в метро даже какие-то приложения собирал помню... ну а вообще без клавиатуры не дело

Comment: Я знаю, одного молодого человека, который диктовал маме текст программы, а она его вводила в ЭВМ. При нынешнем развитии техники с помощи всяких яндексов Вы легко решите проблему.

Comment: Стивен Хокинг вообще буквально одним пальцем набирал свои научные труды.

Comment: Но я бы посоветовал пойти придумать как заработать денег и купить комп и изучать программирование с большой эффективностью. Я бы так сделал

Comment: Клавиатура самая дешевая новая стоит в районе 300 рублей. Я сейчас печатаю на клавиатуре, которую покупал за 360 рублей. Купите новую или найдите подержанную на каком-нибудь Авито.

Comment: @insolor с деньгами любой вопрос можно решить бесплатно надо!

Comment: @HTO, ну значит печатайте бесплатно на экранной клавиатуре манипулятором типа "мышь".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А что, религия запрещает с телефона писать код? Установите себе, например приложение (видимо вам для Android) Python - ну и пишите на телефоне себе на здоровье. Конечно на компе - удобнее, особенно с клавиатурой. :)
Сам когда то в 1987 начинал программировать с программируемого калькулятора Мк-61... компов тогда практически не было в частном пользовании, только в организациях (и то в редко каких). :)

Comment: В `1087` думается и с калькуляторами было тяжко... Счеты максимум ))

Comment: хех... :) опечатался в цифре года. Поправил. Но да, счёты тоже были! :)

Comment: У меня нокиа 3310

Comment: @HTO тогда только в мечтах... мысленно. хотя... можно и на бумаге, если у вас руки есть, конечно и пальцы. В любом случае- сочувствую вам. :)))

Comment: @NykSu, раз уж предаваться ностальгии, то я тоже начинал с МК-61, правда уже ближе к концу 90-х, потом был ZX Spectrum, потом его не было, и приходилось именно так и программировать - на бумаге)

Comment: @insolor в 1988 году на бумаге (в тетрадке) написал первую игру на бейсике - морской бой. и только через год удалось ее проверить в работе на компе-приставке Микрон, появился доступ к компьютерному классу на Микронах. А годом ранее  была попытка запустить СМ-ЭВМ заброшенную шефами техникума, где работала моя мама. Перфолента порвана была - как раз которая подключала терминал... (монитор с клавиатурой)... в единственном экземпляре была и кусочка не хватало.  :)

Answer (score 4):

- Если телефон на iOS или Android, то на него можно установить приложение для программирования. Если повезёт, то у приложения даже может быть прикольная клавиатура, на которой можно свайпать кнопки в 4 направлениях чтобы вводить 4 или 5 разных символов не переключая раскладку.
- Если есть Android с рутовыми правами (впрочем, я не уверен в их необходимости), то можно на него установить termux, который позволит в неком подобии виртуалки делать что угодно, в том числе программировать и запускать код. Правда, скорее всего только в режиме командной строки и с соответствующими редакторами (хотя, может где-то есть расширение для GUI). У меня так на AndroidTV сервер на nodejs крутится. К termux'у есть дополнение, позволяющее закидывать команды в автозапуск. Если ставить из Google Play, то сам termux бесплатен, а за расширения к нему придётся заплатить. Если ставить из f-droid, то всё будет бесплатно. Но termux и расширения должны быть установлены из одного источника, иначе не взлетит.
- Если с перечисленное выше не подходит, то можно использовать онлайн-компиляторы. С отладкой будет так себе, но в большинстве случаев писать вполне можно. Я довольно часто ими пользуюсь во-первых, потому что лень что-то запускать чтобы накидать небольшой примерчик, а во-вторых, поскольку это позволяет использовать языки, которых у меня на компе в принципе нет.

  Наиболее популярны:

  - https://ideone.com/ - много популярных языков программирования, впрочем .net'ные там уже устарели.
  - https://tio.run/ - куча всего, много изотерики для code golf'а.
  - https://jsfiddle.net/ - песочница для небольших веб-страниц.
  - https://codesandbox.io/ - песочница для веб-приложений с использованием популярных фреймвёрков.
  - https://godbolt.org/ - можно что угодно делать с Си и Си++.
  - https://dotnetfiddle.net/ - песочница для .net-языков (C#, VB.NET, F#) различных версий, в том числе самых современных.
  - http://codepad.org/ - довольно старая штука - кажется, компиляторы Си/Си++ (а может и вообще все?) тоже старые и немного более лояльны к UB. К тому же, вместо IDE простое текстовое поле, так что нетребователен к браузеру - [работает](http://codepad.org/ikUOaEsV) в IE10+, но не работает в IE9.
  - https://www.typescriptlang.org/play - тайпскрипт компилируется в javascript и есть возможность запускать код.